# Entity Framework error on a MacBook Pro M1 running Windows 11 via Parallels

Tags: entity-framework, parallels

I have a 2021 MacBook Pro M1 that is running Windows 11 via Parallels.

I'm working on a Windows Forms project (Visual Studio 2022) that is using EntityFramework. When I create a new EntityFramework model the next error occurs:
[Error after creating new EF model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owImb.png)
After trying to compile the app, the next erros occur:
[Errors while running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Xp9.png)
I have a Windows laptop and I did the exact same installation process of VisualStudio 2022 and when creating a new EntityFramework model, everything works "out of the box".

If anyone has any ideas to what is causing the problem I would appreciate the answer very much.
Thanks.

I tried fresh install of Windows 11 on Parallels.
I tried fresh install of Visual Studio (multiple times).
I tried installing EntityFramework package via NuGet Package Manager.

And nothing worked. Always the same errors.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess without the environment(s) in front of me, I would start with eliminating broken nuGet package references. .Net Framework projects will store hint paths pointing to the /packages folder where the packages are typically not checked into source control, but if the NuGet packages file/references are broken/missing then they will be dead references which can cause all kinds of dramas. Same goes if a developer goes and starts tinkering with references without using Nuget PM. Look at what packages Nuget think each project are using against the actual references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that I didn't install any NuGet packages. It is a fresh install of VS2022 on a fresh install of Windows 11 for ARM. That same fresh install on a Windows laptop runs fine and there is no errors. Could the ARM CPU architecture cause the problem? I have already made several Windows Forms apps using Parallels on M1 MacBook Pro (ARM CPU) but this is the first time I'm using EntityFramework and now I came to this error...

Comment: AFAIK EF Core doesn't support edmx designers, so if you're running on an ARM64 my guess is that you should be looking at EF Core 6 or 7 which would generally aim to use code first or schema first via entity type configuration / convention, not designers. I don't have experience with Mac & Parallels.

Comment: I just tried the same process on VS2019 and it works :). So the problem is within VS2022. The only problem now is that VS2019 is not made for ARM and is very slow on ARM Windows but at least I can do some work now... So now the question is can I make VS2022 work to or is this a job for Microsoft :)?

Comment: AFAIK Microsoft is going down the ARM road too so I hope that VS2022 will soon work as it should...

Comment: Steve thanks for the answer, so the problem was that I was using DB first option and EF was not able to make edmx model and that was the whole problem. It works when i use options  you mentioned.

Comment: On VS2019 even the model options works and creates a edmx model...

Comment: Yeah I suspect the dependencies for the designer have more to do with the VS version than the EF version.  VS2019 would likely be setting up a project for .Net Framework by default and EF6 which does support edmx designers for DB First. VS2019 only supports up to .Net Core 5 I believe, Where VS2022 can set up .Net Framework projects but would likely be using .Net Core by default with EF Core 6 or 7. For ARM I'd suspect you would be wanting to run Core not Framework in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue. Seems that MS is not supporting the port yet for EDMX and also the Data & Storage Workloads for ARM yet.